# How add to cache file image to Django HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

How can I solve this?

How add cache header in HttpResponse?
Now the file is not cached.This module is needed to search and return photos or gifs.

> Just need to cache the file on the client in the browser.

my views:

```
def q(request, slug, name):

arr = {
    'png': 'image/png',
    'jpg': 'image/jpeg',
    'gif': 'image/gif',
}

    current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    image_data = open(path, 'rb').read()
    response = HttpResponse(image_data, content_type = arr[extension])
    last_modified = current_time - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    response['Last-Modified'] = last_modified.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
    response['Expires'] = current_time + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=315360000'
    response['Date'] = current_time
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'

    return response
```

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=900
Content-Length: 767365
Content-Type: image/gif
Date: 2019-05-06 20:21:25.134589
Expires: 2019-06-05 20:21:25.134589
Last-Modified: Sun, 05 May 2019 20:21:25 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.3
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Request headers:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8088
If-Modified-Since: Sun, 05 May 2019 20:21:14 GMT
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Why don't you let your webserver handle static resources?

Comment: So what's not working? it looks like the response headers are correctly set according to what you're showing. your last line sets `response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'` which seems to contradict what your want.

Comment: @thebjorn he might be receiving all requests from a CDN. I would personally use whitenoise to serve the files in that case (no need to go through the entire django stack), but if most requests to static files are handled by a CDN anyway, there no real harm in serving the first one via django.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks for the answer! I removed `response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'` and cache don’t  work

Comment: after you removed it, what do you see in your response headers in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Django uses middleware to set the cache headers of your responses. In order to override what the middleware is settings, you should use the `@cache_control` view decorator or the `patch_cache_control` function, as [described here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers) so that the middleware knows this takes precedence and doesn't override the headers:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(public=True, max_age=315360000)
def q(request, slug, name):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

After I set MIDDLEWARE, it all worked.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your code to get `Cache_Control` added to your settings

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(private=True, max_age=3153600)
def q(request, slug, name):
    ....
```